# I can't make new intent

Tags: android, android-intent

my problem with new intent , the problem is with this:    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.test.test1/com.test.test1.facebook}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

`package com.test.test1;

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener,
        OnItemClickListener, OnRotationFinishedListener, OnCenterClickListener {
    public static final String ARG_LAYOUT = "layout";


    private TextView selectedTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set content view by passed extra
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        int layoutId = extras.getInt(ARG_LAYOUT);

        setContentView(R.layout.sample_with_background);

        // Set listeners
        CircleLayout circleMenu = (CircleLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_circle_layout);
        circleMenu.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        circleMenu.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        circleMenu.setOnRotationFinishedListener(this);
        circleMenu.setOnCenterClickListener(this);

        selectedTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_selected_textView);
        selectedTextView.setText(((CircleImageView) circleMenu
                .getSelectedItem()).getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(View view, String name) {
        selectedTextView.setText(name);


        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.main_calendar_image:
                // Handle calendar selection
                break;
            case R.id.main_cloud_image:
                // Handle cloud selection
                break;
            case R.id.main_facebook_image:
                // Handle facebook selection
                break;
            case R.id.main_key_image:
                // Handle key selection
                break;
            case R.id.main_profile_image:
                // Handle profile selection
                break;
            case R.id.main_tap_image:
                // Handle tap selection
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, String name) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getResources().getString(R.string.start_app) + " " + name,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.main_calendar_image:
                // Here is my problem i cant start a new intent why ?
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), facebook.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                break;
            case R.id.main_cloud_image:
                // Handle cloud click
                break;

            case R.id.main_facebook_image:
                // Handle facebook click
                break;}

    }

    @Override
    public void onRotationFinished(View view, String name) {
        Animation animation = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, view.getWidth() / 2,
                view.getHeight() / 2);
        animation.setDuration(250);
        view.startAnimation(animation);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCenterClick() {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.center_click,
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }



}
```

`

Comment: `have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?` ???

Comment: yes i tried every ways, like this
<activity android:name=".facebook"></activity>
like that
<activity android:name="com.test.test1.facebook"></activity>
still not working

Comment: Are you sure? The error says that you don't declare in manifest. Check the package and stuff like that

Answer (score 2):

change this line in your code.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(SampleActivity.this, facebook.class);
```

you have declare Facebook activity in your manifestfile.xml

Comment: That worked for me too, because I was in another this context :D
The error-message is a bit confusing then.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your manifest have not facebook activity if have declared it but still can not start intent then you can check R.id.main_calendar_image view really get clicked

Comment: i used ur code now sir, i get the same problem, nothing solved :(

Comment: do you have get exception or forcelose dialog @AhmedAtef

Comment: to be more clear i'm using this project can any body download it and use new intent please 
<br>
https://github.com/szugyi/Android-CircleMenu

Comment: @GiapLee not sure sir,, because i'm using sample project i didn't start it from scratch.

Comment: @GiapLee it works when you click it, i used this code only                    setContentView(R.layout.facebook);
and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason why you can't start the new intent is because you are using lowercase instead of uppercase for that facebook class.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Facebook.class);
```

Comment: If so, there will be a compile error, but it seems that this code can run.

Comment: @AhmedAtef after you changed it to capital, make sure you also change the AndroidManifest name to .Facebook:  <activity android:name=".Facebook"></activity>

Comment: @the7th i did the changes in manifest to Capital too but nothing solved here's the project files its cool please download it and try to make new intent
https://github.com/szugyi/Android-CircleMenu

Comment: @AhmedAtef what StartActivityForResult does? Or should you use StartActivity instead?

Comment: He is getting the error in runtime. Changing lowercase / uppercase it will be a compilation issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using view.getContext() use the full Activity.this way.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(SampleActivity.this, Facebook.class);
```

Oh and do ensure that it is declared in your manifest